# How do I use the AND function and the MATCH function together to get something that is not "No" and has not been returned previously

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data and need to return all values that aren't "No". 
I.e., I want to create, in another column,
a list of all the values from Column `E` that aren't "No". 
There will never be duplicates in the original data
(other than the multiple repetitions of "No").

```
    E 
5   No  
6   No  
7   IC3  
8   No   
9   J1   
10  J2
11  J3
12  No
```

At the minute I am can get the first value not equal to "No".
I am trying to use the MATCH function to return values <>"No" AND <>[values in previous cells].

I have the following formula in cell L12

```
{=INDEX($E$5:$E$12,AND(MATCH(TRUE,$E$5:$E$12<>"No"),MATCH(TRUE,$E$5:$E$12<>$L$5:L11)),0)}
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: What is the problem with your existing formula? Do you expect to have replicates in the original data (e.g. "J2" twice)?

Comment: After the first result it will return "No"

Here is the formula for the 1st result:

={INDEX(E5:E11,MATCH(TRUE,E5:E11<>"No",0))}


Basically I want it to return IC3 in the first cell, J1 in the next cell, then J2 in the cell after that ect ect....

Comment: And there will never be replicates in the original data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data from **A1** through **A14**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="No","",A1)
```

and copy down.  Then in **C1** enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$14,SMALL((IF(LEN($B$1:$B$14),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($B$1:$B$14))))),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

Comment: Dude you are a genius! When i see that many brackets in an excel formula I know some serious brain power is going on there.  Does exactly what I needed it to :)  Thanks man, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula, used to determine the expected number of returns, in e.g. L1:

`=COUNTIF($E$5:$E$12,"<>No")`

Then this formula in your first cell of choice:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$L$1,"",INDEX($E:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(E$5:E$12)/(E$5:E$12<>"No"),ROWS($1:1))))`

(You will need a small modification if you are using a pre-2010 version of Excel.)

Copy this formula down (though not the one in L1) until you start to get blanks for the results.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that doesn't require a helper column. Assuming your data starts at A1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$14,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$14<>"No",ROW(A$1:A$14)-MIN(ROW(A$1:A$14))+1,""),ROW())),"")
```

Confirm as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter, and autofill down. The way it's written it has to start at row one, but you could tweak the last ROW() to start somewhere else if you need to.